# Android studio using external libraries that aren't jars, can't import

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I'm trying to add https://github.com/TooTallNate/Java-WebSocket into my project. I added the project via File->Project Structure->Import Module then added the project in.

The project does add successfully, at least it looks like it.

But when I go on in and try adding:

```
import org.Java_websocket;
```

It can't seem to find the package, so perhaps I'm not adding it in the right way. How would I get it added in the right way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The module that's using Java-WebSocket needs to have it selected as a dependency. Go to module settings, then dependencies, then add Java-WebSocket as a dependency.

Comment: It doesn't offer to do that on the project that needs to use it, it only offers that on itself

Comment: There should be a "+" button on the dependencies page. Click it, select "Module Dependency", and then choose the module you need to import.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a great tutorial i found, while i had the same problem with importing my LibGDX projects

https://i.stack.imgur.com/wWez1.jpg

this tutorial will go threw on how you add your dependencies with pictures to follow along with it helped me a lot, hope it does the same for you

Cheers